# Unicoin Rep In Chat

Tags: discussion, unicoins

Would is be possible to make the Unicoin Reputation reflect in the chat? I was going shock the JavaScript room as a joke before they saw the sidebar but that wasn't happening haha.

Comment: No. This will create more (unnecessary) load on the system.

Comment: This whole event is "unnecessary load"..? (It's funny and I support it, don't get me wrong)

Comment: They currently modifies the webpage on client side. To make your inflated reputation visible to other people, it would require changes in the server side to support it, which is too disruptive to the normal operation. The minimal change to current system to support this would be: storing whether the power is activated for a certain user and fetch that information everywhere the power is affected.

Comment: I understand, but you're assuming a lot about the system. How do you know it would be too disruptive?

Answer (score 4):

They wouldn't see your inflated rep on the site, so this naturally carries over to chat. All of the powers that you buy are for your enjoyment, you can save the moments with some screen shots if you like.

If we made inflated rep more 'real', we'd also have to do the same with *deflated* rep, which would probably make our support system explode :)

Comment: However, [the support system seems robust enough](http://i.stack.imgur.com/0nchL.png)

Comment: The support system is made out of meat.

Comment: Ok. Meat and robust enough. [But they never turn their backs on you](http://www.probodybuilding.com/eventgallery/d/41889-3/am-pre-women-fitness-0455.jpg)

Comment: Still, would be cool to send some real goodies to the top miners. Excluding those using bots, if it can be detected. :-D